# apache: block request via RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

On my apache server I want to block every request containing the string *test*.

e.g. 
https://example.com/test/index.php

This should be blocked via the .htaccess file, since the url contains *test*.

Can you please help me creating the regex statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple rule at top of your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /test/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to block *test* but allow *test/allowed* (to make an exception for this particular case when 'allowed' is written behind)?